# ImportError: cannot import name 'fitpack'

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, spyder

**pip 18.0**

**python 3.6**

**Spyder 3.2.8**

**OS: Windows 10 Pro**

Bellow error and not able to run deep-ann.py

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-83540d56f55d>", line 1, in <module>

    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

  File "C:\Users\virus-attack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>

    from .data import Binarizer

  File "C:\Users\virus-attack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 18, in <module>

    from scipy import stats

  File "C:\Users\virus-attack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 345, in <module>

    from .stats import *

  File "C:\Users\virus-attack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 171, in <module>

    from . import distributions

  File "C:\Users\virus-attack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 10, in <module>

    from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,

  File "C:\Users\virus-attack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 16, in <module>

    from scipy.misc import doccer

  File "C:\Users\virus-attack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>

    from scipy.interpolate._pade import pade as _pade

  File "C:\Users\virus-attack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py", line 175, in <module>

    from .interpolate import *

  File "C:\Users\virus-attack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 26, in <module>

    from . import fitpack

ImportError: cannot import name 'fitpack'
```

Comment: If you used pip to install packages that can be installed with conda (like scipy), then you most probably corrupted your Anaconda installation and you have to reinstall it. That's because pip and conda packages are not compatible.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, Yeah, I think I need to re-setup everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing/reinstalling Scipy. Here you can find a similar issue https://github.com/soft-matter/trackpy-examples/issues/22